# Hosea 6.9: KJV "by consent" or ESV/LEB "by Shechem"

Tags: genesis, referent-identification

In Hosea 6.9:

KJV reads:

> And as troops of robbers wait for a man, So the company of priests
> murder in the way by **consent**: For they commit lewdness.

Whereas ESV has:

> As robbers lie in wait for a man, so the priests band together; they
> murder on the way to **Shechem**; they commit villainy.

And LEB:

> Like bandits lying in wait, so is a band of priests; they murder on
> the road to **Shechem**; indeed, they commit a monstrous crime.

Whereas LXX (LES) has:

> And your strength is a pirate’s. Priests hid the way. They killed
> **Shechem**, because they did lawlessness.

and the Vulgate aslo refers to the city Shechem:

> Et quasi fauces virorum latronum, particeps sacerdotum, in via
> interficientium pergentes de **Sichem**: quia scelus operati sunt.

Here is the MT:

> וּכְחַכֵּ֨י אִ֜ישׁ גְּדוּדִ֗ים חֶ֚בֶר כֹּֽהֲנִ֔ים דֶּ֖רֶךְ
> יְרַצְּחוּ־שֶׁ֑כְמָה כִּ֥י זִמָּ֖ה עָשֽׂוּ׃

Is the KJV incorrect here? One advantage of the reference to a band of priests murdering on the road to Shechem is the reference to the events of Genesis 34, in which Simeon and Levi abuse the Law, specifically circumcision, in order to commit murder, rape, and theft, in response to Shechem's love for and desire to marry Dinah, and so it is appropriate reference to passage about desiring *chesed* ("loyal love") over sacrifice. However it would be nice if we could get more confirmation that the events of Gen 34 are really being referenced in this prophecy.

### UPDATE

Looking at the 13 times the KJV uses "consent" in the OT, we have:

Zeph 3.9  "...To serve him with one consent [shekhem]"

Whereas the LEB has: "to serve him ⌊in unison⌋".

with a textual note that "*ehad shekhem*" or "one shoulder" means "unison" or agreement. So it appears that KJV might be interpreting "shekhem" as "shoulder" and then taking that to mean "unison" or "agreement", hence "consent". Perhaps this is a stretch, but it's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: The main idea is that of [highway robbery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highwayman).

Answer (score 2):

I, along with every other reference I could find, cannot understand why the KJV elected to render שֶׁ֑כְמָה (shekmah, "to Shechem") as "by consent".

Even the NKJV, translates this Hebrew word as "to Shechem".

The pre-KJV versions that I could find have the following:

- The LXX translation also has Σίκιμα, "Sikma" (= Shechem).
- The Clementine Vulgate also has, "Sichem".
- Jerome's Latin Vulgate as "Sychem"
- The Duay-Rheams has "Sichem".
- The Wycliffe Bible has "Sichem".
- The Luther Bible has "Sichem"

The only exception I found was the Geneva Bible which has "consent".

The only versions that retain "by consent" (or similar) are the KJV and those completely dependent upon it such as Jubilee Bible 2000 and King James 2000 Bible.

Even the proper name "Shechem" means "shoulder" so this is no help either.

Comment: I added an update, where perhaps "shoulder" is taken to mean "consent". This is the best I can do now.

Comment: I'm not going to mark this as an answer because I think there is something more going on here. E.g. the KJV translators were not prone to making dumb errors. I ordered a copy of "translating for king james" to see if there is some explanation of their thinking. I also think the interrupted construct form is playing a role here somehow, so this deserves some deeper digging.

Comment: All pre-KJV English translations that I have read agree with the KJV's rendering for this verse.

Comment: @user21676 - such as which?  The Tyndale translation was only the NT.  The Clementine Latin has Shechem.  The Duay-Rheams has "Sichem", Jerome's Latin Vulgate has "Sychem".  The Wycliffe Bible has "Sichem".  The only exception I found was the Geneva Bible which has "consent".  Even the Luther Bible has "Sichem".  So, what do you refer to?

Comment: @I said English; no I did not include 'Wycliffe' for obvious reasons since in being a translation of the Vulgate it is redundant. Basically there are 7 of them: 1535, 1537, 1540, 1560, 1568, 1599, 1602.

Comment: By that definition, Coverdale's 1535 is also a translation from the Latin the same as Wycliffe's, so it should not count either.  The Matthew Bible (1537)was just the Coverdale Bible in the section Psalms to Malachai so it does not count either.  The same is true of the Taverner's Bible of 1539 and his "great Bible.  So the only real versions here are the Geneva Bible (1560) and the Bishop's Bible (1568).  The Geneva Bible was re-published in 1599 and 1602.

Comment: @Dottard Coverdale does not say 'Shechem' in Hosea 6:9 ok; your generalizations are not helpful.

Comment: @user21676 - I did not say it did: in fact it says "The multitude of the prestes is like an heape of theues, murtherers & bloudthurstie: for they haue wrought abhominacion."  BUT - that does not say anything about "consent" either.